# JSON manipulation - count keys with same value, create new object with count as value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, transform

I want to count the JSON nodes having the same date, and create a new object with the date as the key and the count as the value.

So, using either jQuery or vanilla JS, how would I turn this:

```
[
  {
    "date": "January 1"
  },
  {
    "date": "January 1"
  },
  {
    "date": "January 1"
  },
  {
    "date": "January 1"
  },
  {
    "date": "February 14"
  },
  {
    "date": "February 14"
  },
  {
    "date": "July 8"
  },
  {
    "date": "July 8"
  },
  {
    "date": "July 8"
  },
  {
    "date": "December 11"
  }
]
```

Into this:

```
[
  {
    "January 1": 4 // Number or String "4", doesn't matter
  },
  {
    "February 14": 2
  },
  {
    "July 8": 3
  },
  {
    "December 11": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: This is a fairly simple task using one of several different loops/array methods. What problem are you encountering achieving the goal and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "date": "January 1"
  },
  {
    "date": "January 1"
  },
  {
    "date": "January 1"
  },
  {
    "date": "January 1"
  },
  {
    "date": "February 14"
  },
  {
    "date": "February 14"
  },
  {
    "date": "July 8"
  },
  {
    "date": "July 8"
  },
  {
    "date": "July 8"
  },
  {
    "date": "December 11"
  }
]

let counter = {}

data.forEach(function(obj) {
    var key = obj.date
    counter[key] = (counter[key] || 0) + 1
})

console.log(counter)
```